# How to Get the String of the Title of the Item Selected From a NSPopUpButton in Xcode(Swift or Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

So I have looked at the developer AppKit documentation and found

```
var titleOfSelectedItem: String? { get }
```

My plan is to receive the string of title the pop up button item and to use it in an if statement. like so

```
 func UPDTmathG(_ sender: Any) {
        var titleOfSelectedItem = (sender as AnyObject).String?() ---i don't know how to declare it
            if (titleOfSelectedItem = "A+") {
                var mathPoints = 4.3;
```

Does anyone know how to properly declare the variable to be the title of the most recent NSPopUpButton change. My objective for this project is to create a weighted gpa calculator. Swift or Objective C solutions are welcome even though my code here is written in swift.

Thanks

------edit-----
In the playground I ran this

```
var mathPoints: Double = 2.5
var sciencePoints: Double = 2.5
var englishPoints: Double = 5
var totalPoints : Double = englishPoints+sciencePoints+mathPoints;
```

It worked fine totalPoints was = to 10.
But when I implemented it

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var mathPoints: Double = 0
    var sciencePoints: Double = 0
    var englishPoints: Double = 0
    var totalPoints: Double = mathPoints+sciencePoints+englishPoints
```

I get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sender is an NSPopupButton then you would have to change the sender type from Any to NSPopupButton and access the title by:

```
var titleOfSelectedItem = sender.titleOfSelectedItem
```

This will return an optional String, so simply make sure that you are checking that it is not null, and then you can also check if that title is equal to "A+" in the same line:

```
var mathPoints: Double = 0 //or your default or initial value for mathPoints
if let title = sender.titleOfSelectedItem, title == "A+" {
      mathPoints = 4.3
}

//use mathPoints accordingly
```

Comment: That worked! I set it up but im receiving two errors the unused variable one(I can't figure it out cause I'm using the variables multiple times) also it says expected declaration. I'd appreciate it if you could look at the edit to see if theres any gleaming beginner issues. Thanks:)

Comment: The unused variable one is a warning that would most likely be associated with the mathPoints variable. Make sure you are using that variable. I suggest declaring it out of scope and using it appropriately, I will edit the question showing how.

Comment: Unrelated but do you know the proper syntax for adding variables because I was able to add the just fine in the playground(example above). But when I tried to implement in code I kept getting "cannot use instance 'mathPoints' within property initializer, property initializers run before 'self' is availlible'. I'm sure this is a beginner error.

Comment: By the way ur a huge help

Comment: @ZokeSurfer this means that you're using self before initialization is finished. This could happen if you are trying to initialize a variable using another variable or also if you are using the above code in the initializer before super.init is called. A quick google search will find you many answers on this issue. I also suggest reading up on Apple's swift guide for proper use of initializer inheritance and overriding https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203

Answer (score 1):

The second problem: (You should write a new Q for that.)

```
func UPDTmathG(_ sender: Any) {
  if let title = (sender as AnyObject).titleOfSelectedItem, title == "A+" {
    var mathPoints = 4.3; // Here you define a NEW local var. The ivar is NOT used
  }
  if let title = (sender as AnyObject).titleOfSelectedItem, title == "A" {
    var mathPoints = 4;  // the same issue
  } 
}
```

You define an extra local var and use that local var instead of using the ivar (inner scope overwrites outer scope). Simply remove the `var` at the beginning of the statement.